# Is there a way to reveal an item in the Finder from Launchpad?

Tags: finder, launchpad

Sometimes I will see something that does not really belong in Launchpad—a readme, for instance—and I'd like to see it to move it. Sure, I can close Launchpad, open the Applications folder, and hunt for it there (perhaps in subfolders), but it seems to me that there ought to be an easier way. Is there? I can't seem to find one. Right-clicking, sadly, seems to do nothing.

I'm not trying to delete items that are in Launchpad from my drive; I just want to see them in the Finder, so that I can move them around or perform other operations on them.

Comment: Have you tried by putting the applications folder in dock so when you open it comes out some kind of launchpad? Or are you trying another thing?

Comment: That's a fine idea, one that I have used for many years—but it requires organizing all of the icons in the Applications folder into subfolders. Since macOS comes with this nifty Launchpad that allows you to leave your applications in the root Applications folder but still organize them, I figured I'd try to use that instead.

Comment: I don't see how this is an exact duplicate. I want to *move* items, not delete them from my disk.

Comment: What is an exact duplicate?

Comment: Duplicate question. This was marked as a duplicate, but that has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is No, there's no way to reveal an item in the Finder from Launchpad.

However, there *is* a relatively easy way to remove items from the Launchpad, which is what I really wanted to do, and it does not require moving the item out of the Applications folder: [Launchpad Manager](http://launchpadmanager.com). It's an inexpensive utility that helps you manage your Launchpad, and, crucially, remove any items you'd like from it.

Answer (score -2):

There is an easier way.

While in Launchpad press and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd>key, then select the "x" on the icon to remove it.  The icons will "shake" like they do on the iPhone.

[image: Delete Apps from Launchpad]

There is a caveat; you can't delete apps that are either required by macOS or didn't come from the App Store.  In that case, you must go through the Applications folder.

See [Use Launchpad on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202635) on Apple Support for more information.

Comment: Since not everyone has an iPhone, not sure how good or appropriate mentioning, "The icons will "shake" like they do on the iPhone.", is. Maybe just say something like... The icons will noticeably "shake" side to side.

Comment: I'm not trying to delete the item from my hard drive, which is what (to my understanding) that option does. I just want to see it in the Finder, so that I can perhaps move it to another folder (for instance, if it's a readme file or something) and get it out of LaunchPad.